# Read single string from file in C script and send it as part of an url

Tags: c, curl

I have a C Script which sends data from a barcode scanner to a server. 
What i'd like to do is, read a single string of digits like "1234567890" from a file (which only contains these 10 digits) , and use it as part of the url curl is sending to. i was hoping to find something like

but it doesn seem that easy

my script looks like this right now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])

    { 
    while (1)
        {
        char buf[256],syscmd[512];
        int i;

        /* Get next barcode */
        printf("Waiting for bar code [q=quit]:  ");
        if (fgets(buf,255,stdin)==NULL)
            break;

        /* Clean CR/LF off of string */
        for (i=0;buf[i]!='\0' && buf[i]!='\r' && buf[i]!='\n';i++);
        buf[i]='\0';

        /* q = quit */
        if (!strcmp(buf,"q"))
            break;

        /* Build into curl command */
        sprintf(syscmd,"curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=%s\"",buf);

        /* Execute--this will wait for command to complete before continuing. */
        system(syscmd);
        } 
    return(0);
  }
```

what i want is that my url looks sth like "http://www.xyz.com/1234567890/test/order/complete?barcode=%s" where the number 1234567890 is read from a file

Comment: Can you provide sample content of the file?

Comment: yes:  1234567890
thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below is the program similar to yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100], syscmd[512];

    while(fgets(buf,255,stdin) != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    register int i = 0;
    while(buf[i] != '\0') {
            ++i;
    }
    buf[i-1] = '\0';

    if (buf) {
            sprintf(syscmd,"curl \"http://www.xyz.com/test/order/complete?barcode=%s\"",buf);
            system(syscmd);
    } else {
            printf("Need input");
    }
}
```

Way to execute:

./hit_url < barcode.txt

Here in barcode.txt I kept 1234567890.